# routerLink appends my link

Tags: angular

I have a menu navigation component that appears on all pages:

I have some links like this:
    - Following
    - Followers

When I'm on http://localhost/#/ the links are created ok eg :

```
- http://localhost/#/network;scrollTo=%23Following
- http://localhost/#/network;scrollTo=%23Followers
```

But If I click on one the other shows something like this :

```
- http://localhost/#/network;scrollTo=%23Following/(network;scrollTo=%23Followers)
```

How can I reset this?

Comment: add a `/` to the beginning of link `<a routerLink=[/network']></a>`

Comment: @FabioAntunes , yup it worked. I tried with ./, but it was obviously wrong. Thanks

Comment: @FabioAntunes, I'll accept your answer if you post it

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are using relative urls, that's why `routerLink` keeps appending them. You should check the Relative Navigation [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#relative-navigation).

No slash in the biggining or `./` means a relative url to the current one

A starting  slash means an absolute url

Comment: I want to go to external URL but localhost:4200 appends to my link when I am using [href] attr