# Angular routing keeps adding to the end of URL

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have added a link like below

`<li><a routerLink="about"><span>About</span></a></li>`

But when I click on the link the address will be

`http://localhost:4200/home/about`

But how I want it is `http://localhost:4200/about`

when I keep clicking **About** the url keeps adding the /about part to the end of the URL

`http://localhost:4200/home/about/about/about`

Any help is much appreciated since I am new to angular.

Comment: /about - [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40103616/1298824)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

```
<li><a routerLink="/about"><span>About</span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try this

```
 <span routerLink="/about" > About</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

add / in routerLink

```
<li><a routerLink="/about"><span>About</span></a></li>
```

or u can do like this

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['/about']"><span>About</span></a></li>
```